# Using /Zm with CL In Visual Studio 6.0

Tags: c++, visual-c++, command-line, compiler-errors, visual-studio-6

I am using a software called Symbols for engineering modelling. It produces a .cpp file for the model, along with a .bat file for command line compiling.
It uses a compiler to produce a .dll file which it then calls back to complete the simulation.

It uses Visual C++ 6.0 Complier. I am getting and error *xxx.cpp(64952) : fatal error C1076: compiler limit : internal heap limit reached; use /Zm to specify a higher limit*

I tried adding `/Zm500` to the bat file, but it produced no change. There were some [suggestions online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zm-specify-precompiled-header-memory-allocation-limit?view=msvc-160) to use `/MP`. Tried that. That also didn't work. I also tried adding a User Defined Environment Variable CL with values as `#/Zm500` `/Zm500` `=/Zm500` etc. but none of those worked.
I am not an expert in Programming and can't do much edits to the code as it is auto generated.

Anyone can help regarding this? Why `/Zm` is not working? Should I be doing something else?
I am using Visual Studio 6.0 in Win10 Machine. The .cpp file has 151,000 lines of code.
Adding below the contantes of .bat file

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO --------------------Configuration: 8 Coil No MC 45L 1Rd - Win32 Release--------------------
SET OLDPATH=%PATH%
PATH="C:\WINDOWS";"C:\WINDOWS\system32";"C:\WINDOWS\COMMAND";"F:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Common\MSDev98\Bin";"F:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\Bin";"F:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Common\Tools";"F:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Common\Tools\WinNT";
ECHO Compiling...
CL.EXE  /Zm500 /MP /nologo /I "D:\Symbols\SYMBOLS Sonata\Bin" /I "D:\Bondgraph_Works\Header_Files" /I "F:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\Include" /I "F:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\ATL\Include" /I "F:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\MFC\Include" /MT /W3 /GX /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_WINDOWS" /YX /Fo"8 Coil No MC 45L 1Rd.obj" /Fp"8 Coil No MC 45L 1Rd.pch" /Fd"" /FD /c "8 Coil No MC 45L 1Rd.cpp" 
ECHO Linking...
LINK.EXE /libpath:"D:\Symbols\SYMBOLS Sonata\Bin" /libpath:"D:\Symbols\Borland\BCC55\Lib" /libpath:"F:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\Lib" /libpath:"F:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\MFC\Lib" kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib  /nologo /subsystem:windows /dll /incremental:no /machine:I386  /def:"8 Coil No MC 45L 1Rd.def" /out:"8 Coil No MC 45L 1Rd.dll" "8 Coil No MC 45L 1Rd.obj" "Library.Lib"
PATH=%OLDPATH%
ECHO End of Compilation.
```

Comment: This is for the current compilers and I don't have access to VC 6.0 docs - _"...If the compiler emits the C1076 error message, an accompanying C3859 message specifies the factor argument to use when you recompile by using the /Zm compiler option...."_ Do you get the `C3859` message ?

Comment: @RichardCritten No I didn't get C3859 message. That's why I tried /MP since that is mentioned in a doc that if C3859 is not accompanying /MP is to be used.

Answer (score 0):

See if you can increase the size of the /Zmnnnnn number.
/Zm10000 I don't recall the upper limit.
Microsoft has a hard limit at some point on symbols it can keep track of.
Visual Studio 6.0 is a CIRCA 1998 compiler.  In comparasion it's like riding to work on a horse compared to driving a Tesla.

I don't beleive Visual Studio 6.0 supports the /MP switch.  Its that old.

You can use the tiny_cc pre-processor thats one solution we used when we needed to pre-process large files.  Tiny_cc is open source, but you would have to build it and I don't recall the switch to CL.exe to tell it to use that pre-processor.  But thats the solution we used.

If you were 'C' savvy you might be able to split the file in two, and/or try using pre-compiled headers which might reduce the symbols the pre-processor sees.

But /Zm500 seems to be a small number I think you can go higher.